# Python: Mantener en movimiento un rectangulo en el widget Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy intentando hacer que un rectangulo, al presionar una de las flechas se dirija infinitamente hacia el lado de la flecha, por ejemplo si presiono la flecha arriba quiero que vaya infinitamente hacia arriba y que solo cambie de direccion al yo presionar otra flecha.
ya intente utilizando el metodo `root.after` y no me funciono.
¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto? o ¿es necesario hacerlo de otra forma?

Este es mi codigo:

````
root.title("Snake game")
root.geometry("+340+30")
Pantalla = tk.Canvas(root,width=600,height=600,bg="#212121")
Pantalla.pack()

Snake = Pantalla.create_rectangle(0,0,30,30,fill="white")


def Mover(direccion):

    if Pantalla.coords(Snake)[2] > 600:

        Pantalla.move(Snake,-660,0) 

    elif Pantalla.coords(Snake)[2] < 0:
        Pantalla.move(Snake,660,0)

    elif Pantalla.coords(Snake)[3] < 0:
        Pantalla.move(Snake,0,660)

    elif Pantalla.coords(Snake)[3] > 600:
        Pantalla.move(Snake,0,-660)


    if direccion == "Up":       
        Pantalla.move(Snake,0,-30)      
    elif direccion == "Down":
        Pantalla.move(Snake,0,30)
    elif direccion == "Left":
        Pantalla.move(Snake,-30,0)
    elif direccion == "Right":
        Pantalla.move(Snake,30,0)


root.bind("<Up>",lambda _:Mover("Up"))
root.bind("<Down>",lambda _:Mover("Down"))
root.bind("<Left>",lambda _:Mover("Left"))
root.bind("<Right>",lambda _:Mover("Right"))


root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como comentas `after` es la solución, solo que debes tener en cuenta que `after` solo temporiza la llamada a la función una sola vez, para que se mueva indefinidamente, la propia función debe llamar a `after` de nuevo en cada ejecución:

```
import tkinter as tk



def cambiar_dir(nueva_direccion):
    global direccion
    direccion = nueva_direccion

def mover():
    global direccion
    if pantalla.coords(snake)[2] > 600:
        pantalla.move(snake,-660,0) 

    elif pantalla.coords(snake)[2] < 0:
        pantalla.move(snake,660,0)

    elif pantalla.coords(snake)[3] < 0:
        pantalla.move(snake, 0, 660)

    elif pantalla.coords(snake)[3] > 600:
        pantalla.move(snake,0,-660)


    if direccion == "Up":       
        pantalla.move(snake,0,-30)      
    elif direccion == "Down":
        pantalla.move(snake,0,30)
    elif direccion == "Left":
        pantalla.move(snake,-30,0)
    elif direccion == "Right":
        pantalla.move(snake,30,0)

    root.after(int(1000 / vel), mover)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snake game")
root.geometry("+340+30")
pantalla = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg="#212121")
pantalla.pack()

vel = 1 # movimientos/segundo
direccion = "Right"

snake = pantalla.create_rectangle(0, 0, 30, 30, fill="white")
root.bind("<Up>",lambda _: cambiar_dir("Up"))
root.bind("<Down>",lambda _: cambiar_dir("Down"))
root.bind("<Left>",lambda _: cambiar_dir("Left"))
root.bind("<Right>",lambda _: cambiar_dir("Right"))

pantalla.after(int(1000 / vel), mover)

root.mainloop()
```